# Web form for marketers 2.5 report

Tags: web-forms-for-marketers

I have installed WFFM 2.5 running on Sitecore 7.5 MVC

The MVC form has been submit successfully but when I'm trying to open the Form Reports, the data is always showing 0 point to all field.

This is my connection string configuration:

< add name="reporting" connectionString="user id=rabobank;password=password;Data Source=.;Database=Rabobank.Sitecore.Analytics.Local"/ > 
< add name="analytics" connectionString="mongodb://localhost/rabo_Sitecore_Analytics" / > 
< add name="tracking.live" connectionString="mongodb://localhost/rabo_tracking_live" / > 
< add name="tracking.history" connectionString="mongodb://localhost/rabo_tracking_history" />

I check on Sitecore lock I've got an error:

ManagedPoolThread #8 15:50:32 WARN  Failed to create counter 'Sitecore.System\Threading.ThreadDataModified'. Sitecore has no necessary permissions for reading/creating counters
ManagedPoolThread #3 15:50:32 WARN  Failed to create counter 'Sitecore.System\Threading.ThreadDataRead'. Sitecore has no necessary permissions for reading/creating counters
ManagedPoolThread #10 15:50:32 WARN  Failed to create counter 'Sitecore.System\Threading.BackgroundThreadsStarted'. Sitecore has no necessary permissions for reading/creating counters

I set up the Network Service user as an app pool Identity. Now the error has gone and seems the cache has been created. However when I open the Forms Report I still got no update. I notice that it will takes time before the data get into database but I still got no update until now.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add "Save to Database" Save Action on your form. After added you will see submitted forms in the report in the matter of seconds.